# Link symbols with absolute address to PIC binary

Tags: c, embedded, bootloader, position-independent-code

I'm creating a new image that is constructed from multiple binary images (combined together through python script). The problem is that the last binary image must be compiled with fPIC, but the previous images are not. The last image (the one compiled with fPIC) reuse the functions from the other binary images with `--just-symbols`.

The problem is that when I'm trying to call the function from the other binary (symbol received by `--just symbols`), the address of the symbol is relative and not absolute which this causes a hard fault.

How do I link symbols with absolute address to PIC binary?

Code example:

File fun.c compiled into fun.elf stripped to fun.bin:

```
int fun(int a,int b)
{
    print("help\r\n");
}
```

File fail.c compiled with `-fPIC` to and `--just-symbols=fun.elf`:

```
int fail(void)
{
    fun(1,3); 
}
```

In the sample, the address of fun in fail.bin is relative instead of absolute.

Comment: If I understood this correctly, you've got a statically linked executable and you want a PIC library that will have these static addresses hardcoded?

Comment: almost I have an executable compiled with PIC and i what it to had those symbols hardcoded

Comment: For future reference: Using the 3 letter acronym "PIC" for embedded systems is not a good idea, since everyone immediately think Microchip PIC rather than position-independent code.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong with the call within `fail()` to `fun()`?  Even if it does a relative offset to reference *fun()*, what is the problem?

Comment: How are the "previous images" linked? Specifically, to which addresses.

Comment: each image is linked independently. with the C_FLAGS  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wall -Wextra 
linker flags  -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -Xlinker --print-gc-sections
what actually happens is I'm loading the PIC image into offset and 'fun' address is the actual address of the function + the offset

Answer (score 0):

So, after some more research I found out this cannot be done.
you cannot force a pc of an application that was compiled with the fPIC flag to not use PIC for special symbols (in my case symbols from --just-symbols).

the solution I choose is actually parsing the not PIC elf file and get the addresses for the needed functions. use those addresses and cast them to the needed function.